# Sql Query detecting Apostrophe and return ERROR

Tags: .net, sql-server

I have a query containing like operator.

```
select * from schools where Schoolname like 'mary's%'
```

this is my query when i type `mary` it shows correct search results. but when I put apostrophe it returns an error. how to over come this? any suggestions?

Comment: And that1s why we worry about SQL injection  attacks

Comment: required reading: https://xkcd.com/327/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need double `''` to make a valid *SQL* string :

```
select * from schools where Schoolname like 'mary''s%';
```

However, you should make it as variable to avoid *SQL* injection attack :

```
declare @schoolName varchar(max) = <string here>

select * from schools where Schoolname like '%' + @schoolName + '%'
```

Answer (score 5):

> how to over come this? any suggestions?

Parameters:

```sql
select * from schools where Schoolname like @schoolName
```

or maybe

```sql
select * from schools where Schoolname like '%' + @schoolName + '%'
```

and add a parameter called `@schoolName` with value `"mary's%"` (or `"mary's"` with the second example)

As a full example with Dapper:

```cs
string schoolName = ... // from the form/request/whatever
var schools = connection.Query<School>(
    @"select * from schools where Schoolname like '%' + @schoolName + '%'",
    new { schoolName } // <== the parameters
).AsList();
```